# A doubt regarding the proof of Lebesgue's lemma.

Tags: general-topology

The proof of Lebesgue lemma is given on pg. 191 of Munkres' Topology (Second edition). 
I would like to quote the argument

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a covering of $X$. Assume $X$ is not an element of $A$. As $X$ is compact, choose a finite subset of $A$ that covers $A$, namely $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$. Choose $C_i=X-A_i$ for each open set $A_i$, and define for every $x\in X$ the function $f:X\to \Bbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}{d(x_i,C_i)}$. **We see that $f$ is continuous.**

I don't see why $f$ has to be continuous. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the continuity of the distance function. That is, for each $i$, the mapping 
$$f_i:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto d(x,C_i)=\inf_{z\in C_i} d(x,z)$$
is continuous. This follows from the fact that $|d(x,C_i)-d(y,C_i)|\le d(x,y)$.

To see this, note that for all $w\in C_i$ the following holds: 
$$\inf_{z\in C_i}d(x,z)\le d(x,w)\le d(x,y)+d(y,w).$$

But then it is also true that:
$$\inf_{z\in C_i}d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+\inf_{z\in C_i}d(y,z).$$

So we have 
$$d(x,C_i)-d(y,C_i)=\inf_{z\in C_i}d(x,z)-\inf_{z\in C_i}d(y,z)\le d(x,y).$$ You can use the same argument to show that:
 $$d(y,C_i)-d(x,C_i)=\inf_{z\in C_i}d(y,z)-\inf_{z\in C_i}d(x,z)\le d(x,y).$$
So then $|d(x,C_i)-d(y,C_i)|\le d(x,y)$ and $f_i$ is continuous. Since $f=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i$ it is also continuous.